# How to make ALV subtotal lines editable or any workaround?

Tags: alv, dynpro

In an ABAP program, I need to provide a way for the users to change the value of all cells belonging to a group at once.

`CL_GUI_ALV_GRID` does not allow to make cells of subtotal lines editable. An ALV tree view does not allow editing of nodes either.

Is there a way around it ?

Comment: ALV lines can be grouped into subtotals.

Comment: The cells of subtotal and total lines cannot be edited directly, but you may force their values programmatically during the event "after refresh", in which you call the method `GET_SUBTOTALS` and you may change any cell of the subtotal/total lines. So, one possible workaround would be to define a custom button to display an additional editable ALV grid whose values can be changed by the user and injected back to the subtotal/total lines of the main ALV grid.

Comment: That was the closest thing I could come up with. But this is not ideal from a user point of view. Switching from one ALV to another can be confusing. But this does not have to be solved with an ALV table, I could use a ALV Tree if I can make it editable. Surely there is a way to display lines under a group and allow for some kind of grouped editing ?

Comment: Maybe it could work if you tweak `cl_gui_alv_grid` to operate directly on the Windows control (`gridview.ocx`), like the tweak to "merge cells" (alike the Excel cell merge feature), but I strongly don't advise, you'll spend lot of time for almost no added value and no guaranteed result. ALV tree is a wrapper of `cl_gui_column_tree`, which is definitely NOT editable.